# Concatenated strings, missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, string

I've isolated this piece of script on my page (it's not the only script but the rest is irrelevant I believe). From what I can tell this should be a valid way of making a string span multiple lines in JavaScript.

```
<script>

    var about-dialog-html = ' <div id="disclaimer"> ' +
                            '   <p> Some text </p>  ' +
                            '</div>                 ';

</script>
```

But my browser is throwing a

```
Syntax Error: missing ; before statement
```

on the line beginning with `var`

Comment: JavaScript variable names can't contain a dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot have **- (hyphen)** in your variable names.

*about-dialog-html* is invalid, use `about_dialog_html` instead.

*NOTE: You can use this awesome tool to check if variable name is valid or not : https://mothereff.in/js-variables*

Answer (score 0):

Try simply

```
var about_dialog_html = '<div id="disclaimer"> <p> Some text </p></div>' ;
```

Comment: a) explain *why* he should try that, and more importantly b) how is your answer different from Vijay's?

Answer (score 0):

A hyphen "-" is not a valid character for naming variables in JavaScript. Replace - (hyphen) with underscores.

Mostly the hyphen is used for arithmetic operators and not for naming the variables.

https://mothereff.in/js-variables